# Where are web pages stored on web clients?

Tags: html, client

Once a web client connects to some web server via HTTP/HTTPS it downloads a web page code (lets say HTML) along with all the content (images to display, etc.).
Where is all this stuff typically stored on the PC? or all of this code/stuff reside in RAM?

Sorry if its a very basic question, couldn't find any answer to this.

Comment: It depends of your http client - eg. different for chrome, different for firefox...

Comment: Lets say on chrome

Comment: on which operating system?

Comment: Really? is it that specific? Windows 7.

Comment: yes it os-specific. Ok - so now type in google: `where chrome store/cache webpage files on windows 7`